# How to add a class to last table row

Tags: php

I want to add a class to every last `<tr>` of a main category. I don't want to add the classname to every `<tr>`. What can I change in my script?

Like this:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
    <td></td>
    </tr>

<th></th>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="test">
    <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>


 <table class="data forum">   

        <? foreach ($this->mainCategories as $mainCategory): ?>
            <tr>
                <th><strong><?= $this->escape($mainCategory->fcName) ?></strong></th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th><strong>Topics</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Laatste topic</strong></th>
             </tr>
             <? foreach ($mainCategory->getSubCategories() as $category): ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><a href="<?= $this->url(array('categoryid' =>  $this->escape($category->getID()), 'controller' => 'forum', 'action' => 'subcategory'), 'default', true) ?>"><?= $this->escape($category->getName()) ?></a></td>
                    <td><?= $this->escape($category->fcDescription) ?></td>
                    <? if ($this->escape($category->numTopics) > 0): ?>
                        <td><?= $this->escape($category->numTopics) ?></td>
                        <td><?= date_create($this->escape($category->last_topic))->format('d-m-Y H:i') ?></td>
                    <? else: ?>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <? endif ?>
                </tr>
             <? endforeach ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="split"></td>
            </tr>

         <? endforeach ?>

 </table>
```

Comment: Unless you need a particular structure (for scraping or something), I would recommend just using the `:last-of-type` pseudo-class.

Comment: I don't think a CSS pseudo-class will work because the last "mainCategory" `<tr>` isn't necessarily the last `<tr>` in the table.

Comment: i want at every main category. Because i want to style rounded corners after every main category.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the `count` of your `$this->mainCategories` variable and test for the last one against a counter variable...

```
$count = count($this->mainCategories;
$current = 0;

<?
    foreach ($this->mainCategories as $mainCategory):
        $current++;
?>
    <tr<?= $current == $count?' class="someClass"':''?>>
```

**Update:**

Let's look at a simplified version as a proof of concept:

```
<?php
$mainCategories = array("Eins", "Zwei", "Drei");

$count = count($mainCategories);
$current = 0;

    foreach ($mainCategories as $mainCategory):
    $current++;
?>
    <tr<?= $current == $count?' class="someClass"':''?>>
        <td><?= $mainCategory ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This produces the following HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>Eins</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Zwei</td>
</tr>
<tr class="someClass">
   <td>Drei</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: No this doesnt work.  Now this class is added only in the last main category with every subcategory tr.